# Unable to boot and enter BIOS

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, bios, dualboot

Yesterday I tried to make my laptop dual-bootable(there was already Windows 10, and the second OS I wanted to appear was Ubuntu 20.04). For that I made Live USB using Rufus.

During the installation process I have created an EFI system partition(installer suggests do so), a partition for the whole filesystem and a swap partition. Then the automatic installation began and in a couple of minutes a fatal error occured: `Exexuting grub-install /dev/sda1 failed,and the installation broke down.`

After that I have tried several  times to install Ubuntu with all the available `partition for boot loader` options. As you can guess, they all failed.

Today I have discovered something unusual: after pressing power button there is manufacturer's logo, but black screen after that. Also, I have no ability to enter *Setup Utility settings* (simply speaking BIOS).

To resolve this problem I started searching the web, and nothing helped me.

I tried:

- take out ac adapter, battery, and reset CMOS with holding power button for 40 secondds
- take out RAM and insert it back

Laptop info:

- Asus N56JN
- Intel Core i5 2.8GHz
- RAM 6GB

Also, I don`t think I have access to the CMOS battery because I can't take out one screw having physical damage.

Comment: You can try reinstall the current (or maybe upgraded) BIOS. Get the BIOS from ASUS, put on a bootable USB key and try installing. This comes at some risk so think about it first. You may wish to get the computer serviced if you cannot remove a screw.

Comment: @John How do you think I will update/reinstall my BIOS on my asus laptop without even entering BIOS settings? On official asus page I found only tutorial to do it only like this. If you have another idea, approach or link, please, share it!

Comment: Most BIOS updates I have seen/used initiate the update from the bootable key without entering BIOS to begin with.

Comment: @John So, when I place BIOS file on USB drive, insert it in my laptop, and finally power on -> nothing happens. Still there is an ASUS logo with just black screen afterwards. Could you suggest me doing smth?

Comment: I am not sure (based on my own experience). I will keep looking.